# calculating the rank for today's and yesterday total using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have table as below

```
name  price  date

soap    10    2013-09-18
soap    10    2013-09-18
pens     8    2013-09-18
deos     7    2013-09-18
book    13    2013-09-17
book    13    2013-09-17
soap    10    2013-09-17
pens     8    2013-09-17
```

Based on the above data , i would like to calculate the rank of total selling per item ( based on price as below for today and previous day.

name  totalselling date                  todayrank   previousdayrank

soap        20              2013-09-18         1                        2
pens           8               2013-09-18          2                2
deos           7               2013-09-18          3                        -

if the todays item doesnt exit in yesterday ,then its ranking in previous day should be null.

Comment: After 20 posts you should learn about the code-block. It is a `{}` button in the post editor.

Comment: i m not able to create a table .. let me know if there is any help on that

Comment: I edited your post so you can see.

Comment: i got it how to add tables  thanks a ton...

Comment: we are firing 2 queries to get the desired result .. first we calculate the rank on todays basis and then in the second query we pass the names based on rank and calculate their ranking in the previous date.. the reason this approach is not good enough is bcoz of the performance issue. thatz why i m looking for a query where i get the desired result in a single query..

Comment: you will still need 2 queries. If speed is an issue, consider creating intermediary tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.name,
       a.todaysales,
       a.date,
       a.rank AS ranktoday,
       b.rank AS rankyesterday
FROM
  (SELECT name, sum(price) AS todaysales, date, @n := @n + 1 AS rank
   FROM TABLE , (SELECT @n := 0) alias
   WHERE date=curdate() group by 1  order by count(*))a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT name, sum(price) AS todaysales, date, @n := @n + 1 AS rank
   FROM TABLE , (SELECT @n := 0) alias
   WHERE date=curdate() - interval 1 DAY group by 1  order by count(*))b ON a.name=b.name
```

Comment: adrian its giving me  #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use subselects, date intervals, some variables, a case and some brainwork.
Mix all this together and you will get something like this:

```
SELECT today.*,
       CASE 
         WHEN yesterday.yesterdayrank IS NULL THEN '-' 
         ELSE yesterday.yesterdayrank 
       END
FROM (SELECT @i:=@i +1 AS todayrank,
             name,
             SUM(price) AS price
      FROM test,
           (SELECT @i:= 0) AS foo
      WHERE createdate = DATE (NOW()) - INTERVAL 2 DAY
      GROUP BY name
      ORDER BY todayrank) today
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT @j:= @j +1 AS yesterdayrank,
                    name,
                    SUM(price) AS price
             FROM test,
                  (SELECT @j:= 0) AS bar
             WHERE createdate = DATE (NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY
             GROUP BY name
             ORDER BY yesterdayrank) yesterday ON today.name = yesterday.name
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: SELECT today.name,today.price,@i:=@i+1 as todaysrank,yesterday.price1,yesterday.yesterdaysrank FROM 
( 
 select `name`, SUM(`price`) AS price FROM test,(SELECT @i:= 0) AS foo WHERE date1 = DATE (NOW()) - 
 INTERVAL 2 DAY
        GROUP BY `name`
        ORDER BY price desc
) today
LEFT JOIN 
(  
 select `name`,@j:=@j+1 as yesterdaysrank,price1 from 
 ( 
  select `name`, SUM(`price`) AS price1 FROM test,(SELECT @j:= 0) AS bar WHERE date1 = DATE (NOW()) - INTERVAL 5 DAY
  GROUP BY `name`
  ORDER BY price1 desc
 ) g
) yesterday 
ON today.`name` = yesterday.`name`

Comment: the query given by u was perfect and i modified it to get the desired result